# Complete install a Linux OS to the MacBook Pro

Tags: linux, macos, wireless-networking, mac, macbook

I would like to install Linux on a MacBook Pro machine. It will be a full installation and afterward, will run fully on Linux.

Please, don't ask me why, but, I'm sure I can go back and install OS X at a later time (if needed).

My plan to plug it with 2 external Dell monitors.

Does anyone know if I purchase an Apple wireless keyboard and wireless mouse, will it work in the setup (when running Linux)?

Thank you.

In short: does the Apple wireless keyboard and mouse works when Linux installed in the MacBook Pro?

Answer (score 2):

The standard Apple wireless keyboards and mice use Bluetooth, so they will work just fine with Linux, Windows, BSD, etc...  Be sure to select the Apple keyboard layout when installing Linux to avoid incorrect key mappings. However, Linux should autodetect the keyboard layout.

Additionally, you absolutely can install OS X after the fact.